# How can I stop jquery animation in my slideshow

Tags: jquery, slideshow, jquery-animate

I am using a jquery photo slideshow feature I found online. It contains a div which uses the accordian effect to display the name of the photo currently being shown. The client however does not want the div to "slide" down. He wants it static while still loading the current photos title as they advance. I have an example [here.](http://wms-clients.com/msgs/index.html)

I tried going into the js file and commenting out the parts that I thought cause the animation to the div, but it had no effect. Any ideas on how I could achieve stopping jquery animation on one particular div in my example?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where you'd put this, but this is how you do it.

```
$('#divName').stop()
```

Comment: This makes sense Diodeus and thank you. The problem is I'm afraid i may stop ALL animations in the page, and I only mean to stop one portion of it.

Answer (score 1):

try changing this:

```
$(items[currNo]).fadeIn((timeOut / 6), function() {
    if ($(itemsSpan[currNo]).css('bottom') == 0) {
        $(itemsSpan[currNo]).slideUp((timeOut / 6), function() {
            faderStat = false;
            current = items[currNo];
            if (!mOver) {
                fadeElement(false);
            }
        });
    } else {
        $(itemsSpan[currNo]).slideDown((timeOut / 6), function() {
            faderStat = false;
            current = items[currNo];
            if (!mOver) {
                fadeElement(false);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

to this:

```
$(items[currNo]).fadeIn((timeOut / 6), function() {
            faderStat = false;
            current = items[currNo];
            if (!mOver) {
                fadeElement(false);
            }
});
```

Comment: I didn't see a change Andy. But thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I wasn't sure which js file I should be referring to, and you showed me above that it was s3Slider.js.

Answer (score 1):

Okay. I found a work around that works for me if you're using the s3Slider.js
I think it has to do with the timeOut calculation in s3Slider.js... 
on the page with the images do the following:

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#s3slider').s3Slider({
timeOut: 12000  // --> make it a multiple of 6000 and it will be smooth. only tested with 6000 & 12000
});
});

Answer (score 0):

With the help of both Andy and Diodeus, I think I'm  a lot closer than I was :) I managed to learn that I can give different commands to function lines in jquery files such as

```
$(itemsSpan[currNo]).fadeIn((timeOut/6), function() {
```

I know now that I can replace `.slideDown` with things like `.fadeIn` and get different effects. While I was able to change the imageSpan (which is just a box with the photos title in it) from sliding to fading, I still have not been able to make it just "sit" there and do nothing. I'm hoping the client likes the fade and leave it at that :)